# How to set gradient colour to UIButton in background?

Tags: ios, uibutton, gradient, linear-gradients, cagradientlayer

Am trying to set *CAGradientLayer* for `UIButton`.

But it is not getting exactly. am I doing any wrong ?

am getting ***output*** like

[image: this]

You can see there is some horizontal line

Here is the **code** which I tried

```
let topColor = UIColor(red: 0.62, green: 0.38, blue: 1, alpha: 1).cgColor
let bottomColor = UIColor(red: 0.87, green: 0.51, blue: 0.93, alpha: 1).cgColor
let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
gradientLayer.frame = myButton.bounds
gradientLayer.colors = [topColor, bottomColor]
gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
myButton.layer.insertSublayer(myButton, at: 0)
```

Comment: autolayout or autoresize don't work for `CALayer`

Comment: it's happen because applying gradient before the constraints loaded for view.

Comment: refer -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/52510372/6630644

Comment: you can embedded button in GradientView of subclass UIButton and override layer property

Comment: @PratikSodha, Then how should i fix this issue ? even am writing that code in viewDidLayoutSubviews()

Comment: @SPatel... tried that it didn't work. am getting same output as earlier

Comment: @ammateja number of ways to fix this.. Like you can use create gradient local variable and reframe it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews ` also gradient can be apply using `delay` or also apply in `viewDidApper`. But i prefer using delay block... :)

Answer (score 2):

Create a Designable custom class like this

```
import Foundation
import  UIKit
@IBDesignable class CustomButton:UIButton {

    @IBInspectable var firstColor:UIColor = UIColor.clear {
        didSet {
            updateUI()
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var secondColor:UIColor = UIColor.clear {
        didSet{
            updateUI()
        }
    }

    override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        get {
            return CAGradientLayer.self
        }
    }
    func updateUI(){
        let gradient: CAGradientLayer = self.layer as! CAGradientLayer
        gradient.frame = self.bounds
        gradient.colors = [firstColor,secondColor].map { $0.cgColor }
        gradient.locations = [0.0,1.0]
        gradient.startPoint =  CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)

    }
}
```

from your Identity inspector set your UIbutton class to CustomButtom like this 
[image]

from your Attribute inspector change your gradient color to whatever you want to set [image]

and finally your button will be like this 
[image]

if you want to change the  starting and endpoint to those colors 
just play around with these two values

gradient.startPoint =  CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
     gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)

Comment: thank you for explaining clearly. i gave my custom color on Attribute inspector. But it is not reflecting to button. i mean background of button remains same. I don't know how to show to you here. we can't attach screenshot here

Comment: @ammateja which color did you change gradient color or button backgroundcolor

Comment: gradient color...i mean first color, second color.
already background color is in clear color

Comment: Ok add this in your custom button class 


 override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        updateUI()
    }

Comment: @ammateja did that work for you or else you can share your query here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26424/iosandroidchaosoverflow
here you can share screenshots

Comment: wrote. same issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180787/discussion-between-shakti-and-amma-teja).

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the gradient's frame when the view is laid out:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    myButton.layer.sublayers?.first?.frame = myButton.bounds
}
```