# Gradient in UIView inside UITableViewCell changed after scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cagradientlayer

I have set a gradient color to `UIView` inside my `UITableViewCell`. Everything works fine in the first load but after scroll, the gradient color is loaded again and change the position every time than the actual set condition. Here's my code for implementing gradient color :

what should I do?

**Add Gradient Layer**

```
func gradient(frame:CGRect,colors: [CGColor]) -> CAGradientLayer {
    let layer = CAGradientLayer()
    layer.frame = frame
    layer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.0)
    layer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
    layer.locations = [0.5,0.35]
    layer.colors = colors
    return layer
}
```

**UITableViewCell** **Class**

```
class AllOfferlistCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var lbltitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblPopular: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var VwPercentage: UIView!   
}
```

**tableView** `cellForRowAtindexPath`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! AllOfferlistCell

    cell.lbltitle.text = "Index \(indexPath.row)"

    if self.DataArray[indexPath.row].Flag == "1"{

        cell.VwPercentage.layer.insertSublayer(gradient(frame: cell.VwPercentage.bounds, colors: [UIColor.red.cgColor,UIColor.white.cgColor]), at: 1)
        cell.lblPopular.text = "POPULAR"

    }else{

        cell.VwPercentage.layer.insertSublayer(gradient(frame: cell.VwPercentage.bounds, colors: [UIColor.blue.cgColor,UIColor.white.cgColor]), at: 1)
        cell.lblPopular.text = "50% OFF"
    }

    return cell
}
```

Output :

**First time load**

[image]

**After scrolling**

[image]

Comment: I think its not proper way to work with gradient, create custom view and override layer property with gradient layer. no need to insert layer in tableview's dequeue cell method

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52510372/6630644

Comment: @SPatel I want to display triangle view like this in the top corner of each cell is there any other way to getting output like this?

Comment: In first load, why the the else part is not called?? I mean if is not in blue, neither it is red? The why the cell from( index 3 -5) are not showing gradient??

Comment: @Dimple else part is called but it's load at the bottom according to condition after 10 indexes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create custom view like below

```
@IBDesignable class TriangleGradientView: UIView {
    @IBInspectable var topColor: UIColor = UIColor.red {
        didSet {
            setGradient()
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var bottomColor: UIColor = UIColor.blue {
        didSet {
            setGradient()
        }
    }
    
    override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return CAGradientLayer.self
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        setGradient()
    }
    
    private func setGradient() {
        (layer as! CAGradientLayer).colors = [topColor.cgColor, bottomColor.cgColor]
        (layer as! CAGradientLayer).startPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.0)
        (layer as! CAGradientLayer).endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
        (layer as! CAGradientLayer).locations = [0.5,0.35]
    }

}
```

**Use**

1. set customclass of `VwPercentage` to `TriangleGradientView` in interface builder
2. change `VwPercentage` type to `TriangleGradientView`.

   ```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! AllOfferlistCell
       cell.lbltitle.text = "Index \(indexPath.row)"
       if self.DataArray[indexPath.row].Flag == "1"{
           cell.VwPercentage.topColor = .red
           cell.lblPopular.text = "POPULAR"
       }else{
           cell.VwPercentage.topColor = .blue
           cell.lblPopular.text = "50% OFF"
       }
       cell.VwPercentage.bottomColor = .white
       return cell
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much bhai it's work for me. you deserve  +1 and accept.

Comment: Yo.. @NikunjKumbhani

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve different gradient colors by using array of gradient colors.
Because when you scroll UITableView, cell is reused so gradient color is changing at every reused cell.

Initialize array of gradients colors

```
let primaryGradientColorsArray = [Color1,Color2,Color3];
let secondaryGradientColorsArray = [Color1,Color2,Color3];
```

and in UITableView delegate

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! AllOfferlistCell

cell.lbltitle.text = "Index \(indexPath.row)"

if self.DataArray[indexPath.row].Flag == "1"{

    cell.VwPercentage.layer.insertSublayer(gradient(frame: cell.VwPercentage.bounds, colors: [primaryGradientColorsArray[indexPath.row],secondaryGradientColorsArray[indexPath.row]]), at: 1)
    cell.lblPopular.text = "POPULAR"

}else{

    cell.VwPercentage.layer.insertSublayer(gradient(frame: cell.VwPercentage.bounds, colors: [primaryGradientColorsArray[indexPath.row],secondaryGradientColorsArray[indexPath.row]]), at: 1)
    cell.lblPopular.text = "50% OFF"
}

return cell
}
```

Comment: I know very well, But the dynamic color code comes from the server side.

Comment: Get index from server of color codes or maintain key for color code,
like if you want to show Red color at 50% off then in JSON or XML returned from server side maintain a key value pair in object, such that 
`{
type:"50%"
color1:"RED"
color2:"BLUE"
}`
**Hit like if this helps**