# Gradient background color of UICollection View Cell changes by itself while scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview

I have the following `cellForRow` code

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "SquareCVC", for: indexPath) as! SquareCVC
if let gradient1 = items[indexPath.row].hex_up, let gradient2 = items[indexPath.row].hex_down{
     cell.contentView.setGradientBackground(firstColor: gradient1, secondColor: gradient2)
}else{
     cell.contentView.setGradientBackground(firstColor: "#EFEFF1", secondColor: "#EFEFF1")
}
```

But when I scroll collection view, background color changes by itself
There is my setGradientBackground function

```
func setGradientBackground(firstColor: String, secondColor: String) {
        let colorTop =  colorWithHexString(hexString: firstColor).cgColor
        let colorBottom = colorWithHexString(hexString: secondColor).cgColor
                    
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.colors = [colorTop, colorBottom]
        gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
        gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds
                
        self.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at:0)
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52603164/6630644

Answer (score 1):

Possible issues:

- You are inserting EACH time a layer. Cells are reused, you might have 300 layers added up for each cells for scrolling too much. Except if you override `prepareForReuse()` and remove each `CAGradientLayer`, but it'd be better to have an instance variable directly.
- You are settings the bounds BEFORE the cell got its full frame. Use `layoutSubviews()`

```
class YourCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    var gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

    func setGradientBackground(firstColor: String, secondColor: String) {
        let colorTop =  colorWithHexString(hexString: firstColor).cgColor
        let colorBottom = colorWithHexString(hexString: secondColor).cgColor                
        gradientLayer.colors = [colorTop, colorBottom]

        if gradientLayer.superlayer == nil { //Or insert it on init
            layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at:0)
        }
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        gradient.frame = bounds
    }

}
```